# jQuery: array zero vs function get zero: [0] vs get(0)

Tags: jquery

Is there any reason I should use `$('#x>div').get(1)` when I could instead just use `$('#x>div')[1]`? Is there a difference?

Comment: This is an *exact* duplicate, but I don't have the link.

Comment: That is why I spelled out the words. So it would be easier to find later with a search. Just spelled out a few more words in case it helps. @pst

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nope, no difference. jQuery holds all DOM nodes in an Array.

`$().get(1)` === `$()[1]`

--jQuery source snippet--

```
get: function( num ) {
    return num == null ?
        // Return a 'clean' array
        this.toArray() :

        // Return just the object
        ( num < 0 ? this[ this.length + num ] : this[ num ] );
},
```

As you can see, `.get()` with no arguments will return all nodes as Array. This cannot be accomplished with brackets.

Answer (score 7):

No, and performance is [about the same](http://jsperf.com/get-vs-array) because the creation of a jQuery object dominates array/function access time:

```
Browser      get Ops/sec  array Ops/sec  #tests
Chrome 9     20,555       22,671         2
```

Comment: huh.. I would expect the array method to be **more** efficient since you would not have to go through the function.

Comment: Whoops, Oh, it is.. Sorry I was thinking in terms of milliseconds spent,, not operations per second

Comment: Your comparison is obscured by the fact that in your test you're also doing a comparatively heavy operation (creating a jQuery object and DOM selection). If you remove those from the test, the difference is shown to be enormous. http://jsperf.com/get-vs-array/2 `array: 123,366,553 / get: 4,062,520` So @George's expectation was absolutely correct.

Comment: OP is creating a jQuery object regardless, which dominates performance, so you need to factor it in. Removing it from the test is not realistic.

Comment: Update: In Chrome 47, the [performance](http://jsperf.com/get-vs-array/2) difference has become significantly smaller: `array: 397,779,318 / get: 343,623,455` (this is my local result - failed to load other results)