# jQuery Element Iteration context selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, iteration

I am creating a form validation in jQuery, but I have some problems;

First I iterate over all the to-be-validated elements and push them into an array (I have tried all of the following):

```
1. errorfields.push($("#name"));
2. errorfields.push(document.getElementById("name"));
3. errorfields.push("name");
```

Then, at the end I iterate over these items and want to add an error message.

```
for(var i = 0; i < errorfields.length; i++){
  1. var parent = errorfields[i];
  2. var parent = $(errorfields[i]);
  3. var parent = $("#" + errorfields[i]);
}
```

And all this returns is:

```
[<input>, context: #document, selector: "#name"]
```

If i try to make a jQuery object of the {input}, it returns exactly the same.

Even if i put a line like:

```
console.log($("#name"));
```

It will return this array with context and selector. What can be the problem?

I am unable to execute jquery functions on this object, by the way. Which is the point, seeing that i want to add a 2px red border and a $(parent).after("error message");

Comment: `[<input>, context: #document, selector: "#name"]` is the jQuery object for the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work for you.

```
errorfields.push( $("#name")[0] );
//Get the html element rather than the jQuery element (an object).
```

Then inside your for loop you should have something like this:

```
var parent = $( errorfields[i] );
//This will get you the jQuery element again.
```

[Here is a quick example using divs to show this.](http://jsfiddle.net/aGWsE/)

Comment: This gives me the HTML object, but when i try to wrap it in `$()` in order to manipulate it, instead of returning an object that i can modify i get `[<input>, context: <input>]` which I cannot use or manipulate.

Comment: All you would need to do is `$( errorFields[i] ).addClass('error')`

Answer (score 0):

`$("#name")` will certainly return a jQuery object with all the methods. In your log I think you're only noticing the [owned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) properties. If you look up the prototype chain you'll see all the `$.fn` methods. If `#name` does not exist then the length will be `0`.

If you want to convert a jQuery object into an array you should use [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) or [[].slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
var array = $('.example').get();
```

or:

```
var array = [].slice.call( $('.example') );
```

Comment: Quicker and easier to use [0]. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975716/jquery-array-zero-vs-function-get-zero-0-vs-get0

Comment: @Sam You're talking about grabbing a single element by index. I'm talking about converting the whole object to an array.